# Remove Gnome windows manager and install the Xfce windows manager

Tags: linux, gnome, xfce, gnome-shell

Is it possible to install a different windows manager?

Currently I am using an HP Netbook 210. The windows manager I am using is "gnome-shell" that comes as default with Fedora 15.  However, I am wondering if I could completely remove this and install a different windows manager, such as Xfce 4.8.

I am not talking about completely removing Fedora 15 and then installing Fedora 15 xfce spin.  Just the window manager.

How easy would it be to remove the gnome-shell windows manager and then install xfce 4.8 windows manager? Any steps to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be easy to install another window manager and take if for a spin. You don't even have to remove your current one, in fact it's highly recommended that you *leave it in place*.

Open up your distributions package manager and install the XFCE packages. Then logout and use the menus on the login screen to select a different window manager during your login process.

Answer (score 2):

Install Switchdesk package as well:

```
$ sudo yum install switchdesk
```

Then change your window manager:

```
$ switchdesk xfce
```